# How to make 3 boxes in same line?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Home Boxes Section2 -->
<?php
    for($bx=1; $bx<2; $bx++) { 
        if( get_theme_mod('page-setting'.$bx)) { 
            $bxquery = new WP_query('page_id='.get_theme_mod('page-setting'.$bx,true)); 
            while( $bxquery->have_posts() ) : $bxquery->the_post(); 
                ?>
                <div class="one_third <?php if($bx%3==0){ ?>last_column<?php } ?>">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <?php echo fitnesslite_content(22); ?>
                        <span class="ReadMore"><?php _e('Read More','fitness-lite');?></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php
            endwhile;
        }
        else{?>
            <div class="one_third <?php if($bx%3==0){ ?>last_column<?php } ?>"><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/thumb_02.jpg"><h4><?php _e('sadasdaPage Title','fitness-lite'); ?><?php echo $bx; ?></h4><p><?php _e('Phasellus viverra aliquet magna quis interduming. Sed quis fringilla massa. In ut porttitor felis necing iaculis mi. Proin tempo...','fitness-lite');?></p><span class="ReadMore"><?php _e('Read More','fitness-lite');?></span></a></div>                        
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
<!-- Home Boxes Section -->
```

Here's my problem? How to make them in same line? 
This is the code for 1 box, I paste this 3 times and I get 3 boxes, but the problem is they are not in same line how to make them in same line.

Comment: Try codepen next time, https://codepen.io/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to put a `float: left` for all boxes, so that they can be in the same line when there is enough space.

Alternative approach is to use `display: flex;`, you can read more about the `flex` property at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

If you are CSS beginner, my advice is to use some front-end framework like Bootstrap to give you an idea how to layout page using row and col. Once you familiar with that you can write your own CSS to layout any design you want.

http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Okay i got another problem now .. http://prntscr.com/ea8ppf look ... 3th box is bigger :D

Comment: it probably because the content inside the box is too big. Try to set the `max-width: 100%` for the image inside the box.

Comment: The image size is good now but its again on another line .. http://prntscr.com/ea8s9e

Comment: Yes, it is a little tricky to use float to align things. Try `flex` then, need a little effort to learn but worth it.

Answer (score 0):

using bootstrap css will help you alot,because every workspace in bootstrap is divided into rows and columns and every row has 12 columns. so you can try this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">Box1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">Box2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">Box3</div>
</div>
```

I have used col-lg-4 3 times because a row has 12 columns.4*3=12, so here your row is ready, you can use  further styling as per your requirement but first [get bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to achieve this. See the browser support [here.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.box { 
  flex: 1;
  
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie aliquet nunc eget egestas. Suspendisse nisi felis, commodo volutpat orci suscipit, efficitur fermentum diam. Mauris posuere pellentesque fermentum. Aenean id rhoncus metus. Nullam ac urna sapien. Pellentesque vestibulum, ipsum ac vehicula imperdiet, eros ex elementum arcu .</div>
  <div class="box two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie aliquet nunc eget egestas. Suspendisse nisi felis, commodo volutpat orci suscipit, efficitur fermentum diam. Mauris posuere pellentesque fermentum. Aenean id rhoncus metus. Nullam ac urna sapien. Pellentesque vestibulum, ipsum ac vehicula imperdiet, eros ex elementum arcu, non fringilla risus dolor id eros. Nullam interdum mauris eu augue ornare facilisis. Curabitur purus libero, hendrerit ut diam id, facilisis mattis felis. Nulla facilisi.</div>
  <div class="box three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie aliquet nunc eget egestas. non fringilla risus dolor id eros. Nullam interdum mauris eu augue ornare facilisis. Curabitur purus libero, hendrerit ut diam id, facilisis mattis felis. Nulla facilisi.</div>
</div>
```